# ValueError: possible array in wrong dimensions?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to train a neural network on game inputs. The original code had only 3 key inputs: a, w, d. I'm trying to change this to 9: a, w, d, s, aw, wd, sa, sd, nokeys. Now in training the model I get a ValueError suggesting an array is of the wrong dimensions somewhere. But I can't find anything linking back to the 3 keys I could change to 9 so I'm a bit at a loss.

Here's the error message:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\StefBrands\Documents\GitHub\pygta5 - Copy\train_model.py", line 28, in <module>
    snapshot_step=500, show_metric=True, run_id=MODEL_NAME)
  File "C:\Users\StefBrands\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tflearn\models\dnn.py", line 215, in fit
    callbacks=callbacks)
  File "C:\Users\StefBrands\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tflearn\helpers\trainer.py", line 336, in fit
    show_metric)
  File "C:\Users\StefBrands\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tflearn\helpers\trainer.py", line 777, in _train
    feed_batch)
  File "C:\Users\StefBrands\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 778, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\Users\StefBrands\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 961, in _run
    % (np_val.shape, subfeed_t.name, str(subfeed_t.get_shape())))
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (64, 4) for Tensor 'targets/Y:0', which has shape '(?, 3)'
```

This is where the balancing of the data happens:

```
    # balance_data.py

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
from random import shuffle
import sys

train_data = np.load('training_data-1.npy')

df = pd.DataFrame(train_data)
print(df.head())
print(Counter(df[1].apply(str)))

w = []
a = []
d = []
s = []
wa = []
wd = []
sd = []
sa = []
nk = []

shuffle(train_data)

for data in train_data:
    img = data[0]
    choice = data[1]
    print(choice)

    if choice == [0,1,0,0]:
        w.append([img,choice])
    elif choice == [1,0,0,0]:
        a.append([img,choice])
    elif choice == [0,0,1,0]:
        d.append([img,choice])
    elif choice == [0,0,0,1]:
        s.append([img,choice])
    elif choice == [1,1,0,0]:
        wa.append([img,choice])
    elif choice == [0,1,1,0]:
        wd.append([img,choice])
    elif choice == [0,0,1,1]:
        sd.append([img,choice])
    elif choice == [1,0,0,1]:
        sa.append([img,choice])
    elif choice == [0,0,0,0]:
        nk.append([img,choice])
    else:
        print('no matches')

min_length = 10000


##lengths = [len(x) for x in (w, a, d, s, wa, wd, sd, sa, nk)]
##print (lengths)

min_length = min(len(x)-1 for x in (w, a, d, s, wa, wd, sd, sa, nk))
for x in (w, a, d, s, wa, wd, sd, sa, nk):
    x = x[min_length]


##lengthsafter = [len(x) for x in (w, a, d, s, wa, wd, sd, sa, nk)]
##print (lengths)

final_data = w + a + d + s + wa + wd + sd + sa + nk
shuffle(final_data)

np.save('training_data-1-balanced.npy', final_data)
```

And this is where I get my error when trying to train the model:

```
 # train_model.py

import numpy as np
from alexnet import alexnet
WIDTH = 160
HEIGHT = 120
LR = 1e-3
EPOCHS = 8
MODEL_NAME = 'pygta5-car-fast-{}-{}-{}-epochs-300K-data.model'.format(LR, 'alexnetv2',EPOCHS)

model = alexnet(WIDTH, HEIGHT, LR)

hm_data = 22
for i in range(EPOCHS):
    for i in range(1,hm_data+1):
        train_data = np.load('training_data-{}-balanced.npy'.format(i))

        train = train_data[:-100]
        test = train_data[-100:]

        X = np.array([i[0] for i in train]).reshape(-1,WIDTH,HEIGHT,1)
        Y = [i[1] for i in train]

        test_x = np.array([i[0] for i in test]).reshape(-1,WIDTH,HEIGHT,1)
        test_y = [i[1] for i in test]

        model.fit({'input': X}, {'targets': Y}, n_epoch=1, validation_set=({'input': test_x}, {'targets': test_y}), 
            snapshot_step=500, show_metric=True, run_id=MODEL_NAME)

        model.save(MODEL_NAME)
```

I understand this is not the most clear problem there is but I have no clue where to fix this issue. If any more code is needed that is linked to please let me know and I'll provide it as quickly as possible.

Edit:
Added the tensorflow code:

```
    # alexnet.py

""" AlexNet.
References:
    - Alex Krizhevsky, Ilya Sutskever & Geoffrey E. Hinton. ImageNet
    Classification with Deep Convolutional Neural Networks. NIPS, 2012.
Links:
    - [AlexNet Paper](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/4824-imagenet-classification-with-deep-convolutional-neural-networks.pdf)
"""

import tflearn
from tflearn.layers.conv import conv_2d, max_pool_2d
from tflearn.layers.core import input_data, dropout, fully_connected
from tflearn.layers.estimator import regression
from tflearn.layers.normalization import local_response_normalization

def alexnet(width, height, lr):
    network = input_data(shape=[None, width, height, 1], name='input')
    network = conv_2d(network, 96, 11, strides=4, activation='relu')
    network = max_pool_2d(network, 3, strides=2)
    network = local_response_normalization(network)
    network = conv_2d(network, 256, 5, activation='relu')
    network = max_pool_2d(network, 3, strides=2)
    network = local_response_normalization(network)
    network = conv_2d(network, 384, 3, activation='relu')
    network = conv_2d(network, 384, 3, activation='relu')
    network = conv_2d(network, 256, 3, activation='relu')
    network = max_pool_2d(network, 3, strides=2)
    network = local_response_normalization(network)
    network = fully_connected(network, 4096, activation='tanh')
    network = dropout(network, 0.5)
    network = fully_connected(network, 4096, activation='tanh')
    network = dropout(network, 0.5)
    network = fully_connected(network, 3, activation='softmax')
    network = regression(network, optimizer='momentum',
                         loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                         learning_rate=lr, name='targets')

    model = tflearn.DNN(network, checkpoint_path='model_alexnet',
                        max_checkpoints=1, tensorboard_verbose=0, tensorboard_dir='log')

    return model
```

Comment: You didn't actually share any TensorFlow code, so it's hard to say what's going on, but in any case, it looks like the problem is in the output, not the input. The given targets seem to be of size 4 (four classes, I guess?) while the model expected 3.

Comment: I've added what I hope is the correct tensorflow code. But I also have no idea where this 3 is stated.

Comment: I'd say it's the one in the softmax layer. What I can't tell is whether that 3 should be a 4 or `Y` should be 64x3 instead of 64x4.

Comment: It's running without errors now, just hope its doing the right thing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should change the numbers of classes to 9 from 3 and use one hot encoding for each of the 9 classes. For example, if your classes are a, w, d, s, aw, wd, sa, sd, nokeys, you should encode aw as [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]. After this encoding, it should work fine if you replace 3 with 9 in the softmax layer in the tensorflow model.(in the line with network = fully_connected(network, 3, activation='softmax'))

Comment: Your description is a little hard to follow. Concrete code samples of your first two sentences, plus where they belong in the code, would add to its clarity immensely.